# Dynamically creating multiple chart areas

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts, alignment

I am creating a program which given some data files, creates charts based on these files. Rather than creating multiple charts, I have chosen to create multiple chart areas in a loop and add the various data to the chart areas.  When using some sample data, which is small, the program creates 3 chart areas within a chart and works fine.

However using larger data, the program creates the chart areas but because there are over 10 chart areas to create, they do not fit into the size of the chart and also are aligned vertically rather than horizontally.

What I would like to do is increase the size of the chart fitting in all the chart areas for large data, aligning all the chart areas vertically and allowing the user to view all the chart areas via a scroll bar, since there will be a lot of chart areas using the real data files, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look http://linq2charts.codeplex.com it is great to create chart dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The below are examples of alignment types you can switch to

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Horizontal
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical
```

As for a scroll bar, the chart control doesn't support scroll bars. What I would do is have my original chart contained in some sort of panel/tab *[any container that supports scroll bars]* and then is number of charts required reaches a certain level add another chart below your original and then allow the container to build the scroll bar

```
'when charts required is now 5 create new chart
If Chart1.ChartAreas.Count =4 Then
      Dim OverflowChart As New Chart
      'add a new chart below your current chart and let the container
      'have the scroll bar and not your chart control

End if
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it soon after I posted here which is ironic. For the sake of anyone with similar problems in the future. The way I did it was to:
- Add a scrollbar to the form
- Make the blank chart as big as possible to fit whatever data which was going to be used
- Manually set the position of each chart area using ChartArea.Position and changing the posY for each chart in a loop

This worked great and gave me a lot of control as to how big I wanted the chart areas since ChartAreas.Position also has a width and height attribute and allowed me to easily align the chart areas horiziontally using the y coordinates of each chart area.